# How to set delay for each ImageView separately?

Tags: android, imageview, delay

I wrote the following method for a Blackjack app that I'm working on.

```
public void showCard(View view){

    startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    hitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    standbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Card dealtCardOnePlayer = deck.dealACard();
    Card dealtCardOneDealer = deck.dealACard();
    Card dealtCardTwoPlayer = deck.dealACard();
    Card dealtCardTwoDealer = deck.dealACard();

    player.getCardsInHand().add(dealtCardOnePlayer);
    dealer.getCardsInHand().add(dealtCardOneDealer);
    player.getCardsInHand().add(dealtCardTwoPlayer);
    dealer.getCardsInHand().add(dealtCardTwoDealer);


    playerCardOne.setImageResource(dealtCardOnePlayer.getCardImagePath());
    dealerCardOne.setImageResource(dealtCardOneDealer.getCardImagePath());
    playerCardTwo.setImageResource(dealtCardTwoPlayer.getCardImagePath());
    dealerCardTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
}
```

It basically deals first two cards to the player and the dealer. The last four lines of code set image resources to the ImageViews. I want to set each image resource one second after the previous one. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler`'s `postDelayed()` method for delay specific codes:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //execute code here after 1000 milliseconds
    }
}, 1000);
```

Statically:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {   
       playerCardOne.setImageResource(dealtCardOnePlayer.getCardImagePath());
    }
}, 1000); //1 second

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {   
       playerCardOne.setImageResource(dealtCardOnePlayer.getCardImagePath());
    }
}, 2000); //2 seconds

...and so on
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try placing this between the lines:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This will stop the execution for one second after each imageview is updated.

Comment: This will totally make the app stuck, because it will block the current thread. Instead, use asynchronous methods (Handler, Timer, AsyncTask, etc) so you can simultaneously run something while you're delaying/waiting.

Comment: You mustn't sleep the main thread or any other thread when it comes to developing for android os. This will cause a lag in the UI and will make the app unresponsive